# variable Scope out side the Method

Tags: javascript, canvas

i cann't understand how it's Possible. These properties assign out side the method (image.onload=function())& after method write..

```
image.src="barn.jpg";
canvas.width=500;
```

but using these Properties inside the method.what about variable Scope for it?

```
 var canvas=document.getElementById("myConvas");
                    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

                    var image=new Image();

                    image.onload=function(){

                        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

                    }
                    image.src="barn.jpg";
                    canvas.width=500;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image.src` causes barn.jpg to **begin downloading**, but the browser will also continue executing all code following `image.src`.

So while the image is downloading, the browser also executes `canvas.width=500`.

After the image has fully loaded, it goes back and executes any code inside the `image.onload` function.

So your code actually executes in this order:

1. var canvas=document.getElementById("myConvas");
2. var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
3. var image=new Image();
4. The browser makes a note to call `image.onload` when the image is fully loaded. But the browser does not actually execute the .onload code yet.
5. image.src="barn.jpg";
6. canvas.width=500;
7. ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

Comment: thanx a lot for descriptive answser thanx you sir